# Excel formula returns #value when named

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I am working with the following table in Excel:

[image: Excel image]

The following formula in evaluates normally when entered directly into a cell:

```
=DATE(YEAR(DATEVALUE($A$1)),MONTH(DATEVALUE($A$1)),DAY(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN()))))
```

However, when I try to place put this in the named function `test` and call `=test` in another cell it returns a `#VALUE!` error. The best answer I have come up with after researching is that named formulas and the `indirect` function are not always compatible.

If anyone can shed some light to help explain what I am doing wrong or why I can not put an `indirect` call inside of a named range I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: When you say named function, do you mean a user-defined VBA function? Or do you mean a defined name with the above formula as its "Refers to" value?

Comment: Non-VBA, a defined name like you would create when making a named range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I don't believe INDIRECT will work with a named range - you shouldn't really need such a convoluted formula - try just

`=(C$2&$A$1)+0`

format as date

**Edit**: as per comments below, INDIRECT is OK but I don't think COLUMN() is liked in the named range. ROW and COLUMN functions sometimes behave badly because they return "arrays" even when single values, so you need another function like MAX or SUM to convert {2} to 2, e.g.

`=DATE(YEAR(DATEVALUE($A$1)),MONTH(DATEVALUE($A$1)),DAY(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MAX(COLUMN())))))`

although I think there are shorter methods as I indicated above....

Comment: +1 I like the formula but I am not too sure about what you mentioned `I don't believe INDIRECT will work with a named range` I have used `Indirect` in named ranges and it has worked pretty well...

Comment: No you are right Sid, I spoke too soon - is it correct that INDIRECT doesn't work with a **dynamic** named range? Here I think it is COLUMN() because it returns an "array" like {2} - wrap COLUMN() function in another function like SUM and the named range should work.....

Comment: I tried this `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN()))` in a named range and it worked? Or am I missing something?

Comment: But it somehow doesn't like `=DAY(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN())))` but it was ok with `=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN())))` Interesting... will have to experiment more...

Comment: Yeah, that's why COLUMN and ROW are odd - they work fine in some scenarios but in other cases you have to convert the array to a single value

Comment: Off to bed.. it's already 5:34AM! Will experiment with it more when I wake up... Learnt something new today! `MAX(COLUMN())` in named ranges :)

Comment: Freelancer actually ;) Gnite/Gmorning

Comment: +1 I was using indirect so that I could just call the function and have it evaluate wherever it was called... I'll have to play around with your first formula to see if I can get that to work in my scenario. Wrapping the indirect works regardless though.

Comment: OK if you want to keep INDIRECT but shorten a little then try this one....`=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,MAX(COLUMN())))&$A$1)+0`